# React: Override onClick-Event of parent div element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, react-router

Im struggling with the following: I have a div-Container which contains alot of stuff and a border, by clicking the div i want to fire a onClick-Event which calls a method to redirect me to another route. Within this div-Container i have a small circle which should do some stuff to by clicking on him and activating his onClick-Event. Is there any possibility to "override" the parent div-containers onClick-Event, because every time i click the circle the onClick of the div is fired and i get redirected to the other route. Small snippets:

The container with the circles: `handleExit` should be called whenever clicking at any position within the container, except by clicking on some of the circles with onClick-Events. In this case `handleBackToFirstAssistant` or `handleBackToSecondAssistant` should be called.

```
<div
   className="contentAssistantBorder"
   onClick={this.handleExit}
 >
  ...
  <div className="circleDiv">
     <p
        className="circle"
        onClick={this.handleBackToFirstAssistant}
      />
     <p
       className="circle"
       onClick={this.handleBackToSecondAssistant}
     />
      <p className="filledCircle" />
     </div>
  </div>
```

handleExit:

```
handleExitAssistant() {

 this.props.history.push("/search");

}
```

handleBackToSecondAssistant:

```
handleBackToSecondAssistant() {
  this.setState(
   {
      secondAssistant: true
    },
     () => this.setState({ thirdAssistant: false,  firstAssistant:    false })
  );
}
```

Comment: If I understood the question correctly - look into `event.stopPropagation()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation

Comment: I would also look at examining `event.target`, to see which element the user actually clicked.

Comment: thanks for the comments but i didnt get it working right now

Comment: okey got it now, your attempt did it for me @SakoBu, i just messed up earlier :)